# How to use multiple UseCase in single presenter

Tags: java, android, mvp, use-case, clean-architecture

Consider instagram app with extra useCase

- get post from api
- like post
- flag post
- bookmark post
- comment post

So I have one View(Fragment) and one presenter

I use [clean architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) , So what is the best way to implement presenter and useCase?!

1. inject multiple useCase in one presenter
2. mix multiple useCase in one useCase and inject it to presenter